# How to check precise location status on iOS devices in Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter

iOS 14+ devices have Precise Location switch. How can I check if my app has this permission or not?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you already have location permission. Once, you are there, just use [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) package's helper function `getLocationAccuracy` like this:

```dart
final accuracyStatus = await Geolocator.getLocationAccuracy();
switch(accuracyStatus) {
  case LocationAccuracyStatus.reduced:
    // Precise location switch is OFF.
    break;
  case LocationAccuracyStatus.precise:
    // Precise location switch is ON.
    break;
  case LocationAccuracyStatus.unknown:
    // The platform doesn't support this feature, for example an Android device.
    break;
}
```

Comment: This code sometimes gives incorrect results. There should be a better way to have 100% accuracy whether the user's precise location was ON or OFF.

Comment: This works as expected, and precise works for Android devices too, from version 12.